# say command not working on command line only Debian install

Tags: text-to-speech, gnustep

`uname -a` prints the output `Linux debian 4.9.0-3-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19) i686 GNU/Linux`

I have only the core system utilities installed with no graphical interface.

I did `sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime` to get the `say` command.
when i run the command `say foo` the cursor blinks a few times on the line below the prompt before exiting.

`echo $?` returns `1`

Comment: You may have `spd-say` available. Check, maybe you can use that.

Comment: @tomasz spd-say is not working either. However, a 0 exit status is returned

Comment: That's strange. Try `man spd-say`. Or what do you mean by not working?

Comment: `man spd-say` and `man say` both work. No sound is coming out of the audio device

Comment: Sound in Linux can be difficult. I'd start a new question for this. Something like "no sound in Debian" or "no sound from spd-say in Debian". Is there sound when you use other apps?

Comment: Do you even have libasound2? Here's one for Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/28176/how-do-i-run-pulseaudio-in-a-headless-server-installation It's Ubuntu and old, but may be similar to some extent.

Comment: yes I have `libasound2` already installed

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem while I was using it in a script. You can execute `spd-say -w "Message"` and see the exit code to be sure if spd-say is able to send signal to the speech dispatcher. If it fails, then you have to reset the spd configuration.

To reset the spd configuration run `spd-conf` on terminal.

After running 'spd-conf' a prompt will be appeared where most of the cases the default option can be kept(that means you can press enter several times).
Eventually you will see an option as follows "Can't start Speech Dispatcher. Exited with status 256. Perhaps this is because your Speech Dispatcher is already running.
Do you want to kill all running Speech Dispatchers and try again? [yes] :"
Now press enter and you should hear a message through your speaker.

Now spd-say should work fine.

Comment: @JeffSchaller after you recommended I have tried to explain a little more which I think should be helpful for the users. Thank you.